MLKit text recognition iOS Kotlin Multiplatform
I am trying to use mlkit on ios from a shared module. I added pod's using cocoapods and am trying to repeat this instructions
I get a photo from a common module in the form of a byte array using the "peekaboo" library
@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class, BetaInteropApi::class)
actual fun saveImage(byteArrays: ByteArray?) {
    if (byteArrays != null) {
        val string = NSString.create(string = byteArrays.decodeToString())
        val data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        val imageFromBytes = data?.let { UIImage(data = it) }
        val image = imageFromBytes?.let { MLKVisionImage(it) }
        if (image != null) {
            image.orientation = imageFromBytes.imageOrientation

            MLKTextRecognizer.textRecognizer().processImage(image)
        }
    }
}

There is a "process" in the class textrecognize settings, but largely due to something called "processImage"
Which I don't quite understand what to do with and which asks for a different type of image format it looks like

Type mismatch: inferred type is MLKVisionImage but MLKCompatibleImageProtocol was expected

This is the first time I'm using expect-actual mechanism with cintertop swift. Maybe I basically did not understand how to do it correctly.
Or maybe I can get the result in some other way?

how do you even add cocoapods to a shared module?
